# Honor 5x - Transparent app icons not displaying correctly

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, huawei, app-icons

I just got an Honor 5x and I'm generally not really happy with the UI design, but one thing is bothering me most and it seems like it's actually a bug:

Transparency doesn't seem to work in app icons on the home screen. Basically every icon that doesn't perfectly fill out that weird round square has a colored background. This looks pretty terrible and is really not what I'm used to.

[image]

Is there anything I can do about this?

I have Android 5.1.1, EMUI 3.1 and I installed the Google Now launcher.

Comment: Install another Launcher -> Nova Launcher or Apex Launcher. Then search for Icon packs on the google play store to override the default iconpack.

Comment: So I guess it's not a bug... If anyone else is reading this: I installed Awesome Icons (usable with all launchers) and created/downloaded transparent icons for all my apps. Transparency in icons isn't actually broken, which makes me wonder why all the icons are displayed so hideously.